# Fast moving with long lines when using set wrap

Tags: cursor, wrap

Suppose I have a wrapped line like this

[image]

with the cursor positioned just before the AND (`&`). 
Is there an option to move the cursor just before the OR (`|`) pressing the `<Down>` key ?

This should be possible with a function, but an option would be better, of course.

**EDIT:** The editor hid the `<Down>` text word (now I edited). My intention is not to jump to a specific character but to a specific position. In other words, treating a single line as it were two line

Comment: `t|` to jump to just before the next `|` and `;` to repeat the last `t` command. See `:h t` and `:h ;` for more info.

Comment: Please post actual text and not screenshots in the future. Screenshots are difficult for a number of reasons, and actual text can be copy pasted. Screenshots are usually permissible when they clarify a post (ie something in a colorscheme looks weird), but here I dont think it adds value that a block of text couldnt have done. The fact that the line wraps is almost irrelevant.

Comment: The editor hid the `<Down>` text word (now I edited). My intention is not to jump to a specific character but to a specific position. In other words, treating a single line as it were two line.

Comment: The solution has beeen already threated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833250/make-gvim-treat-wrapped-line-as-new-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:h t`, `:h T`, `:h f`, `:h F` and `:h ;`

For a brief overview:

- You can jump to the next `{char}` with `f{char}` or jump to previous `{char}` with `F{char}`
- You can jump just before the next `{char}` with `t{char}` and jump just after the previous `{char}` with `T{char}`
- You can repeat last `f`, `F`, `t` or  `T` with `;`

All of the above commands take `[counts]` as an argument. So, you can perform `[count]f{char}` to go to the `[count]-th` next `{char}` and similar for all `f`, `F`, `t`, `T` and `;`

**Edit**

The OP edited his question and his actual requirement was to move up and down virtual display lines. You can do that with `:h gj` and `:h gk`

Comment: My first thoughts exactly. This is I never remapped `;` to `:` or used `,` as my leader like so many—its too useful.

Comment: I didn't think anyone would remap `;`. But I used `,` as leader early on because somehow I only knew about `;` and not `,`! But now I use `<Space>` as my leader.